# Insert Drawing.Image into WordprocessingDocument body

Tags: c#, .net, openxml, system.drawing, memorystream

I have a code were I read a docx document in byte array format with System.IO.
Later I make a stream of the docx byte array and use WordprocessingDocument to edit the docx stream.

I edit/replace tags inside the docx stream text that are using hard brackets with a custom inserted text.

Finally at the end I convert the edited docx stream to a new byte array which I later use for other stuff(like using the byte array to create a PDF) but what happens afterward does not matter right now.

The question now is, just as I replace certain tags inside the text, can I insert images? Preferably using a Drawing.Image since that's what my image format is right now.

To make some points clear:

I know that I can save the image using Drawing.Image.Save() and then edit the [IMAGE] tag with a `<img href="our image url that we just saved down.png">` - which is a very easy solution.

BUT. I would prefer if I can avoid saving down unnecessary files and having to rely on linking(which isn't the most stable incase the image disappears)

But to cut the chase, here is the code I'm using so far :

```
Image image = myImage;
byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fullFileNamePath); //Get our docx document as Byte Array
byte[] byteArrayAfterReading;
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    stream.Write(byteArray, 0, (int)byteArray.Length); //Create a stream of the docx byte array document
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true))
    {
       Body body = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
       foreach (var text in body.Descendants<Text>())
       {
           if (text.Text.Contains("[TEST]"))
           {
               text.Text = text.Text.Replace("[TEST]", "Test text here!");
           }
           if (text.Text.Contains("[IMAGE]"))
           {
               text.Text = text.Text.Replace("[IMAGE]", "Image here!"); 
               //Here I should somehowly insert my Drawing.Image
               //I could do this here but would prefer to not 
               //text.Text = text.Text.Replace("[IMAGE]", "<img href='imgurl.png'>"); 
           }
       }
    }
byteArrayAfterReading = stream.ToArray();
}
//After here I do my convert byte array to PDF and save it
```

And all this works great. I just want to figure out a good way to insert my image in there.

tl;dr.

I have a Drawing.Image that I want to insert into my wordprocessingDocument.Document.Body at a certain character string and I would prefer to do this without using html img link to url.

**To update this:**

Bills answer, which basically is a MSDN link shows how to insert an image which works great. *However* it misses some parts like :

1. How do I place the image at a certain spot, in this example my [IMAGE] tag? (Most important)
2. I would prefer to not having to save my Drawing.Image locally inoder to use `'FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))'` i.e is there a way for me to do this with my Drawing.Image directly without saving it down first? (Not important but would prefer this)
3. With the MSDN example my image resolution and aspect ratio got changed, any reasons for that? (Not that important right now but might be in the future)

Comment: There should be a way. Just let me take a look to find out how images are stored in a docx

Comment: @henrikp - How did you implement this line?
//After here I do my convert byte array to PDF and save it

Answer (score 3):

A word doc is nothing but a pile of XML files all put together. Take an existing .docx file, rename it to .zip, and take a look inside. You will see how images are stored, the main doc, styles defined, and all sorts of other good stuff. To add an image, you will need to find the "Part" of the document where you want to add the image. Once found, it is pretty easy to add the image "part" to the parent "part".

Here is quick how-to from the MSDN:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb497430(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb497430%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

```
MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart;
ImagePart imagePart = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Jpeg);
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
{
    imagePart.FeedData(stream);
}
AddImageToBody(wordprocessingDocument, mainPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart));
```

The AddImageToBody looks like this:

```
private static void AddImageToBody(WordprocessingDocument wordDoc, string relationshipId)
{
    // Define the reference of the image.
    var element =
         new Drawing(
             new DW.Inline(
                 new DW.Extent() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L },
                 new DW.EffectExtent() { LeftEdge = 0L, TopEdge = 0L, 
                     RightEdge = 0L, BottomEdge = 0L },
                 new DW.DocProperties() { Id = (UInt32Value)1U, 
                     Name = "Picture 1" },
                 new DW.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
                     new A.GraphicFrameLocks() { NoChangeAspect = true }),
                 new A.Graphic(
                     new A.GraphicData(
                         new PIC.Picture(
                             new PIC.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                                 new PIC.NonVisualDrawingProperties() 
                                    { Id = (UInt32Value)0U, 
                                        Name = "New Bitmap Image.jpg" },
                                 new PIC.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),
                             new PIC.BlipFill(
                                 new A.Blip(
                                     new A.BlipExtensionList(
                                         new A.BlipExtension() 
                                            { Uri = 
                                                "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}" })
                                 ) 
                                 { Embed = relationshipId, 
                                     CompressionState = 
                                     A.BlipCompressionValues.Print },
                                 new A.Stretch(
                                     new A.FillRectangle())),
                             new PIC.ShapeProperties(
                                 new A.Transform2D(
                                     new A.Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
                                     new A.Extents() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L }),
                                 new A.PresetGeometry(
                                     new A.AdjustValueList()
                                 ) { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle }))
                     ) { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" })
             ) { DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U, 
                 DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U, 
                 DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)0U, 
                 DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)0U, EditId = "50D07946" });

   // Append the reference to body, the element should be in a Run.
   wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.AppendChild(new Paragraph(new Run(element)));
}
```

The key part here is knowing how to find the ID of the parent "part" where you want to insert the image.

Comment: I don't have an image downloaded though, just a Drawing.Image and how does this replace a tag?

Comment: And if I use a downloaded image with the provided code it breaks the height/width and aspect ratio of the image.

Comment: Conver that image to a memorystream, and feed it into .FeedData method in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a Picture Content Control instead of the `[IMAGE]` text? You could position it wherever you want in the Word file, give it a "tag" to identify it and then in code access its `SdtContent` and manipulate it however you want.

You would still need to add the new replacement image to the Word document by using:

```
MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart;
ImagePart imagePart = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Jpeg);
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
{
    imagePart.FeedData(stream);
}
```

like in Bill's answer but you would not need to go through the hassle of creating a Drawing.Image image. Just replacing the existing `Blip`'s `Embed` attribute to be the newly added image's id.